# Data inside hibernate interceptor object but null under entity variables - Can't save to repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm on my early days working with Spring and Hibernate and apologies if I'm missing something obvious here but I am a bit confused why I can see an id set for my variable inside a hibernate_interceptor object shown under the debugging tool but it's null for the same variable outside of it.

[image]

This comes from a many to many relationship that exists between the Question and User entities but I've noticed this happening for other relationships as well and it's blocking me from being able to save the new row to my join table.

```
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<QuestionEntity> questionEntities;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "question_favourite",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"))
private Set<QuestionEntity> questionFavouriteEntity;


public UserEntity(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}

public class QuestionEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private Long creationDate;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private UserEntity userEntity;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questionFavouriteEntity")
private Set<UserEntity> userEntities;

public QuestionEntity(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public QuestionEntity(UUID id, String title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

}


@Override
public QuestionFavouriteCreateDto favouriteQuestion(UUID userId, QuestionFavouriteCreateDto qf) {

    if (questionRepository.findById(qf.getQuestionId()).isPresent()) {
        QuestionEntity questionEntity = questionRepository.findById(qf.getQuestionId()).get();
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findById(userId).get();

        questionEntity.getUserEntities().add(userEntity);
        userEntity.getQuestionEntities().add(questionEntity);

        userRepository.save(userEntity);

    }

    return null;
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

As per @christian's  answer I understand this seem to be the desired outcome, and my data saving issue has been resolved under this [other thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762279/many-to-many-relationship-using-spring-boot-not-saving-data-to-join-table/67763013#67763013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate creates proxy classes for your entities to implement lazy loading. The proxy classes are just subclasses of your entity classes that delegate all access through the interceptor to lazy load on the first access to not yet loaded state. Due to object identity guarantees Hibernate has to provide according to the JPA specification, you see the proxy object rather than the real entity. If an entity with a certain id is associated with a persistence context once, it has to always return that object while the object is managed by that persistence context.

So this entity was proxied by some lazy to-one association of a different entity or by using `entityManager.getReference`. When the collection association for `questionFavouriteEntity` is loaded, it sees that the object is part of the persistence context already and uses that object.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed reply. Would you know what to do to bypass this behaviour so I can save to the database? Thanks again.

Comment: No error message but the data is not saved and the join table is always empty.

Comment: Are you using the latest Hibernate version 5.4.29? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I'm on 5.4.25. I was rereading your answer and I think I follow why the id is set under the proxy object but I'm not sure why it's then null under the entity variable? Shouldn't it be populated on both? Also so that I would have access to the fields there such as question and answer entitites that are part of the user entity.

Comment: It would be a waste to set the fields on the proxy object, because all method calls in the proxy class delegate to the interceptor and thus to the actual entity object. If you access fields directly by some reflection library, you will have problems.

Comment: hmm, okay. Thanks. So what I'm seeing is the intended behaviour and the only issue is that it's not saving to the db?

Comment: Right, but it's hard to say what is happening as Spring is involved here as well. If you can create a test case with the test case template I provided you, I can take a look and help you further.

Comment: Thank you for that. Here is the repo for the failing code. https://github.com/francislainy/so/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/com/francislainy/so/backend/service/impl/question/QuestionCommandServiceImpl.java#L123 If that's not enough for you to get what is wrong I can try and create a sample following the template you when I have a bit more time, perhaps over the weekend.

Comment: I'll take a look at the test when you convert it to the template to rule out Spring as a possible source for problems.

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking this long to reply but I got some help under another thread and it's working now, thanks very much.

Comment: HI @FrancislainyCampos can you please share the link of the thread where you resolve this problem? Also, this answer should not be marked as the answer of your qeustion here, since none of the comments or the answer indeed provide a direct resolution to the problem, maybe will be good just to write and answer under your question and adding the link to the thread that helped you and you can mark your own answer as the soution

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I don't remember much about the details for this issue but looking at the dates for my questions here I think this may be the thread I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762279/many-to-many-relationship-using-spring-boot-not-saving-data-to-join-table

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few options but wasn't able to fix them.
Then I realized I need to use

```
FetchType.EAGER
```

This is worked for me.
Just for FYI

**FetchType.LAZY** = This does not load the relationships unless you invoke it via the getter method.

**FetchType.EAGER** = This loads all the relationships.

Pros and Cons of these two fetch types.

Lazy initialization improves performance by avoiding unnecessary computation and reducing memory requirements.

Eager initialization takes more memory consumption and processing speed is slow.

Just posting in case someone doing the same mistake